# convert PDF to image but PDF file path not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm attempting to use the third-party tool IronPdf in ASP.NET with the C# language to convert a PDF file into an image. The following error message appears when I submit the form.

The PDF file path C:\Program Files\IIS Express\Invoice-63457.pdf is invalid. There is no such file.
My code is provided here, below.
See Section

```
<form action="@Url.Action("ConvertPDF","Home")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="postedFile" name="postedFile" multiple="multiple" />
    <br /><br /><br />
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Files" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" />
    </p>
</form>
```

This is my controller part:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConvertPDF(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
{
    var pdf = PdfDocument.FromFile(postedFile.FileName);

    // Extract all pages to a folder as image files
    pdf.RasterizeToImageFiles(@"C:\image\folder\*.png");

    // Extract all pages as AnyBitmap objects
    AnyBitmap[] pdfBitmaps = pdf.ToBitmap();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: In their example they only put the file name, not the entire path, did you try that ? You can extract the file name with `Path.GetFileName`

Comment: @Max I try it but not work. Same error show Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName)

Comment: I think you need to save the submitted file to a location and then you can convert it. 
var FilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files"), fileName);
postedFile.SaveAs(FilePath);

Comment: You have to use the HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream to read the file. The FileName property is just the name, not a path. The file actually does not exists on your file system.

Comment: @Romka, I can understand, I also try in this way but it shows error postedFile.InputStream

Comment: @RichardHousham I am thinking the same way, I think after SaveAs and convert to image then delete the SaveAs file this is how it can be solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reason

The reason for this problem is you trying to load the file in the wrong way. You must use create `PdfDocument` instance from `Stream` or `Byte[]` because when a file upload and you receive that file in your action, the file only exists on `Memory`. according to document, you can create `PdfDocument` instance like below.

```
public PdfDocument(byte[] PdfData, string Password = "", string OwnerPassword = "")
```

or

```
public PdfDocument(Stream PdfDataStream, string Password = "", string OwnerPassword = "")
```

document link
https://ironpdf.com/object-reference/api/IronPdf.PdfDocument.html#constructors

---

### Soultion

You must replace this section

```
var pdf = PdfDocument.FromFile(postedFile.FileName);
```

with this

```
var pdf = new PdfDocument(postedFile.InputStream);
```

Comment: Great @Milad Karimifard